# loadHTMLString Not Working With iOS5?

Tags: html, uiwebview, ios5

The following code does not work with iOS5:

```
- (void)loadURL
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.HTML ofType:@"html"];     
    NSString *markup = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:markup baseURL:nil];
    [markup release];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
                                                 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        // Another controller loads
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

When the web view loads, it does nothing, just an empty screen appears. When I run this in iOS 4.3 it loads the HTML from the bundle.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  In mine I specify a baseURL, which is a file URL into the app bundle.  Also, my HTML specifies a text/javascript script tag which is supposed to load from the app bundle.  If I remove this tag then I start to see html being rendered - otherwise a blank view...

Comment: Man, you should mark accept answers which are correct and Tom's one is correct.

Comment: Sorry about that. Been somewhat busy and forgot about this. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your html includes a script tag that is self-closing `<script src="..." />` tag then this is likely the cause of the problem.

See my own question with solution, here:  [UIWebView loadHTMLString not working in iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840127/uiwebview-loadhtmlstring-not-working-in-ios5)